# Trying to access array offset on value of type null & isset problem in API call loop - 504 Gateway Time-out server

Tags: php

I am building cron job with API calls in loop for DB entries and Have performance issues.

Particularly in this part:

```
    if (!empty($sudCode) && !empty($sudBroj) && isset($sudCode) && isset($sudBroj)) {
        // echo $sudCode . "<br>";
        // echo $sudBroj . "<br>";
        $epredmet = ePredmeti($sudCode, $sudBroj);

        // print_r($epredmet);
        // echo "<br>";

        if (isset($epredmet["data"]["prvi"]["lastUpdateTime"])) {
            $lastUpdateTime = $epredmet["data"]["prvi"]["lastUpdateTime"];
            $dateTime  = str_replace("T", " ", $lastUpdateTime);
            echo $nas . " - " . $dateTime . "<br>";
        }
    }
```

on line:

```
if (isset($epredmet["data"]["prvi"]["lastUpdateTime"])) {
```

I have few Databases and on one when this line is reached sever goes to `504 Gateway Time-out` after 2 minutes.

Hosting company said  that it goes in timeout because Apache web server waits for PHP parser to process data, what ever that means.

**What is strange, is if I leave out that if check i script finishes and I get results but with Notice**: `Trying to access array offset on value of type null in`

because I expect that `$epredmet` after API call looks like this:

```
- array(1) { ["data"]=> array(1) { ["prvi"]=> NULL } } // case not found
- array(1) { ["data"]=> array(1) { ["prvi"]=> array(1) { ["lastUpdateTime"]=> NULL } } }  // case found but lastUpdateTime is not set, null
- array(1) { ["data"]=> array(1) { ["prvi"]=> array(1) { ["lastUpdateTime"]=> string(23) "2021-06-14T22:51:22.171" } } }   // case found and lastUpdateTime is set
```

So what I need to do is filter out just last case where `lastUpdateTime` is set, and all that I read is suggesting to solve it with `isset` but that breaks my script for some reason.

PHP V 7.4

Please advise.

Im attaching full script in case someone notices problem somewhere else:

```
function eSudovi()
{
    $endpoint = "xxx";
    $qry = '{"query":"query{sudovi {id, sudNaziv}}"}';

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $qry);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return json_decode($result, true);
}


$eSudovi = eSudovi()["data"]["sudovi"];

function findSudCode($val, $eSudovi)
{
    foreach ($eSudovi  as $key => $value) {
        if ($value["sudNaziv"] == $val) {
            return $value["id"];
        }
    }
}



function ePredmeti($sud, $pred)
{
    $endpoint = "xxx";
    $qry = '{"query":"query{ prvi:predmet(sud: ' . $sud . ', oznakaBroj: \"' . $pred . '\") {lastUpdateTime}}"}';

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $qry);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return json_decode($result, true);
}






$results = mysqli_query($con, "
                SELECT DISTINCT predf_nas_br, predf_odv,  predf_SUD, predf_SUDBROJ
                FROM PREDMETIFView 
                WHERE predf_SUD <> '' AND predf_SUDBROJ <> '' AND predf_SUDBROJ NOT LIKE '% %'
                UNION ALL   
                SELECT DISTINCT predp_nas_br, predp_odv,  predp_SUD, predp_SUDBROJ 
                FROM PREDMETIPView 
                WHERE predp_SUD <> '' AND predp_SUDBROJ <> '' AND predp_SUDBROJ NOT LIKE '% %'
                ;");
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == "predf_nas_br") {
            $nas = $value;
        }

        if ($key == "predf_SUD") {
            $sud = trim($value);
            if (!empty($sud) && isset($sud)) {
                $sudCode = findSudCode($sud, $eSudovi);
            }
        };

        if ($key == "predf_SUDBROJ") {
            $sudBroj = trim($value);
        };
       


        if (!empty($sudCode) && !empty($sudBroj) && isset($sudCode) && isset($sudBroj)) {
            // echo $sudCode . "<br>";
            // echo $sudBroj . "<br>";
            $epredmet = ePredmeti($sudCode, $sudBroj);

            print_r($epredmet);
            echo "<br>";

            if (isset($epredmet["data"]["prvi"]["lastUpdateTime"])) {
                $lastUpdateTime = $epredmet["data"]["prvi"]["lastUpdateTime"];
                $dateTime  = str_replace("T", " ", $lastUpdateTime);
                echo $nas . " - " . $dateTime . "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
};


// preg_match('/\s/', $sudBroj)
```

**Edit:**

I also tried this:

```
    if (isset($epredmet["data"]["prvi"]["lastUpdateTime"]) && !empty($epredmet["data"]["prvi"]["lastUpdateTime"])) {
```

and this:

```
if (isset($epredmet["data"]["prvi"]) && !empty($epredmet["data"]["prvi"])) {
                if (isset($epredmet["data"]["prvi"]["lastUpdateTime"]) && !empty($epredmet["data"]["prvi"]["lastUpdateTime"])) {
```

Same thing, it hangs, but without it all it work with erros.

Comment: The "offset on value of type null" happens because of this case `Array ( [data] => Array ( [prvi] => ) )` where, of course,  `isset($epredmet["data"]["prvi"]["lastUpdateTime"]` wont find the last key "lastUpdateTime". Maybe you check first with `if (!empty ($epredmet["data"]["prvi"]))`

Comment: Are you sure it's the `isset()`? Did you ever output how many results there are from your query? You're making a curl request for each result. Could be a performance issue there. Try creating a log file with start and endtimes for different parts of the script, so you can analyze where the actual problem lies. Also you could try reusing the curl handle instead of `init()` and `close()` every time.

Comment: @Michel Around 60, and it takes around minute. Api does not have option to fetch all at once at this point. Im thinking of requesting such feature. Log is good idea I will try it. And im bit new to curl usually use JS, can You elaborate on "reusing the curl handle"

Comment: I have also just notcied it also works with ifs ONLY if i leave             `var_dump($epredmet);` before them,  if I comment it it hangs, unbelievable...

Comment: Looks like `function eSudovi()` accepts no variables. So you could easily make it a class, setup the curl handle once and inside the loop call the class function `curl_exec()`.  Saves some overhead connecting and disconnecting.

Comment: Yes `eSudovi()`  is called only once at start and data is saved in `$eSudovi`, and then it is used in loops. I have to say I don't see how making it a class would help, arn't classes just fancy functions? Also endpoints and data is different then `ePredmeti()` function curl api call. I don't understand how same connection you say (?) can be re-used? @Michel Sorry if its silly question, a bit new to this aspect of PHP.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `ePredmeti()`.  Those function names are confusing to me :-) Make you an example as answer. I still supect the timeout has more to do with the curl then with anything you output.

Comment: @Michel Np, I was just about to post question on codereview for suggestions, but I would appreciate if you find time to suggest something. Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do to reuse the curl handle (note: haven't had time to test it, but you'll get the idea).

```
class ePredmeti{
    public $epredmet;
    private $curl,$ini_opt;

   function __construct(){
        $endpoint   ='xxx';
        $headers    = ['Content-Type: application/json'];
        $timeout = 30;
        
        $this->curl= curl_init();
        $this->ini_opt=[
            CURLOPT_URL => $endpoint,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => $timeout,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => $timeout
            ];
        }
    
    public function _exec($sud, $pred){
        $start=microtime(true);
        
        $this->epredmet = null;
        $query_opt=[
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>
             '{"query":"query{ prvi:predmet(sud: ' . $sud . ', oznakaBroj: \"' . $pred . '\") {lastUpdateTime}}"}'
             ];
        curl_reset($this->curl);
        curl_setopt_array($this->curl, $this->ini_opt);
        curl_setopt_array($this->curl, $query_opt);
        $ret = curl_exec($ch);

        if (!curl_errno($this->curl)){
            if(curl_getinfo($this->curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)!==200){
                echo 'HTTP error: '.$http_code.'<br>';
                }
            else{
                $this->epredmet = json_decode($ret,true);
                }
            }
        else{
            echo curl_error($this->curl).'<br>';
            }
        
        echo 'Took: '.(microtime(true)-$start).'<br>';
        }
    }
```

before the `while()` put something like:

```
$mycurl = new ePredmeti();
```

and instead of `$epredmet = ePredmeti($sudCode, $sudBroj);` use

```
$mycurl->_exec($sudCode, $sudBroj);
```

Finally, instead of `if (isset($epredmet["data"]["prvi"]["lastUpdateTime"])) {` you can use

```
if( isset($mycurl->epredmet["data"]["prvi"]["lastUpdateTime"]) ) {
```

The last one works because the class returns `null` on any error and `isset()` checks if a variable exists and is not null.

Comment: There few little mistakes as variable names but it works, much thanks. And times are all over the place, sometimes from 0.01... to even 5. ... And high times do not look too have connection with filled values or  NULLs, Its all over the place. This might be API server problem? Also the problematic DB now sometimes passes and sometimes go to server error.

Comment: Yeah, think the server response from the curl calls is the problem. Could be a slow server, could be you making a lot of calls and that being seen as hammering. But at least you now know where the problem is: it's not in your script.

Comment: It just got to my attention that this GraphQL APi does support multiple cases in one request, it just needs alias in front. So my problems are solved...